"AWS CodeBuild Error: 'Unable to initialize cache download: no paths specified to be cached' in Buildspec.yml"
I am encountering an issue during the PRE_BUILD phase in AWS CodeBuild. My buildspec script attempts to connect to a MySQL database to verify connectivity, but the connection fails with the following error:
[Container] 2024/12/22 20:03:43.966393 Phase complete: PRE_BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2024/12/22 20:03:43.966407 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: if mysql -h "$DB_HOST" -P "$DB_PORT" -u "$DB_USERNAME" -p"$DB_PASSWORD" -e "SHOW DATABASES;"; then 

What I’ve Tried
Verified Environment Variables:
The values for $DB_HOST, $DB_PORT, $DB_USERNAME, and $DB_PASSWORD are fetched from AWS Parameter Store. They appear to load correctly based on the echo debug commands in my buildspec.
Network Accessibility:
The database is hosted on an external server (13.247.100.80)not using RDS. I suspect the issue might be related to networking or security configurations:
Inbound rules on the MySQL server allow connections from my CodeBuild service role's public IP.
The MySQL server is running and accessible from my local environment.
Verified MySQL Configuration:
The MySQL database is configured to accept remote connections on port 3306.
version: 0.2

env:
  variables:
    PHP_83_VERSION: "8.3.8" # Define PHP version

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - echo "Updating system dependencies..."
      - sudo dnf update -y
      - echo "Installing required tools..."
      - sudo dnf install -y unzip git nmap dnf-plugins-core
      - echo "Installing MySQL Community client..."
      - sudo rpm --import https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022
      - sudo dnf install -y https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el9-1.noarch.rpm
      - sudo dnf config-manager --enable mysql80-community
      - sudo dnf install -y mysql-community-client --nogpgcheck
      - echo "Installing Composer..."
      - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
      - sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo "Fetching environment variables from Parameter Store..."
      - export DB_HOST=$(aws ssm get-parameter --name "/expressuddb/db_host" --query Parameter.Value --output text)
      - export DB_PORT=$(aws ssm get-parameter --name "/expressuddb/db_port" --query Parameter.Value --output text)
      - export DB_DATABASE=$(aws ssm get-parameter --name "/expressuddb/db_name" --query Parameter.Value --output text)
      - export DB_USERNAME=$(aws ssm get-parameter --name "/expressuddb/db_user" --query Parameter.Value --output text)
      - export DB_PASSWORD=$(aws ssm get-parameter --name "/expressuddb/db_password" --with-decryption --query Parameter.Value --output text)
      - echo "Environment variables loaded successfully."
      - echo "Testing database connectivity..."
      - |
        if mysql -h "$DB_HOST" -P "$DB_PORT" -u "$DB_USERNAME" -p"$DB_PASSWORD" -e "SHOW DATABASES;"; then
          echo "Successfully connected to the database."
        else
          echo "Failed to connect to the database. Debugging connection..."
          echo "Host: $DB_HOST"
          echo "Port: $DB_PORT"
          echo "Database: $DB_DATABASE"
          echo "Username: $DB_USERNAME"
          exit 1
        fi

  build:
    commands:
      - echo "Building the application..."
      - composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader

  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo "Build completed successfully."

artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
    - '!node_modules/**/*'
  base-directory: /codebuild/output/src

Questions
How can I debug or resolve the Can't connect to MySQL server error in the CodeBuild environment?
Are there specific network or security configurations required for CodeBuild to access an external MySQL server?
Is there a way to test connectivity to the MySQL server without using mysql in the CodeBuild script?

Please format the code in your question to make it readable. If you don't know how, just use the code formatter button in the editor.

Thanks @ Mark B I just formatted it i hope it's readable enough. I am looking forward to seeing you review the error.

You didn't do anything to fix the formatting of the large YAML file you have pasted into your question.

sorry thought you meant the error log.

It looks like in the CodeBuild UI you have enabled the "Custom Cache" option for this job, as documented here. The custom cache option requires you to specify in your yaml file the directories you want to cache. You haven't defined any directories in your yaml file to cache. If you don't want to use that caching feature, you should go into the CodeBuild UI and disable that caching feature for this job.

i don't think the  issue is related to the cache initialization .in my codebuild 'No Cache' option is enabled.
